# ThreadPoolExecutor: how does it reuse threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I read that `ThreadPoolExecutor` has pool of threads and this pool is destined to reduce cost of creation new threads (at least I understood phrase below in such way):

> When you send a task to the executor, it tries to use a pooled thread
>   for the execution of this task, to avoid continious spawning of
>   threads. [Java 7 Concurrency Cookbook]

**BUT**, as I know we have got no way to restart thread in Java.

***Question:*** How does ThreadPoolExecutor avoid creation of new threads?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's very simple - in essence the `Thread`s sleep, waiting to be woken by a task - they run that task and then sleep again.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final BlockingQueue<Runnable> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
    final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    blockingQueue.take().run();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    blockingQueue.add(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Task 1");
        }
    });
    blockingQueue.add(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Task 2");
        }
    });
}
```

The `BlockingQueue` will block a `Thread` while it is empty. When I add an item, and `Thread`(s) currently blocked are awoken and one will take the task (`LinkedBlockingDeque` is thread safe). When the `Thread` is done with the task it goes back to sleep.

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for `ThreadPoolExecutor` describes the logic in detail. All of the constructors for `ThreadPoolExecutor` take a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` - this should give you a hint as so how the logic works.

NB: **This is not the same as busy waiting**. A `BlockingQueue` uses `wait` and `notify` to suspend and wake `Thread`s, this means that the `Thread`s in the pool are not doing any work when they are not processing tasks. A busy wait based approach **would not work** because the `Thread`s would block up all the CPU cores with their polling not allowing the program to proceed (or at least severely impairing it).

Comment: Nice info by Boris. In addition they wrap every call to the worker run method around a try-catch throwable so that the thread is never eixted, no matter what error occurs in the called method. Or some other way to keep track of live threads and make a new one when needed?

Comment: @tgkprog Indeed yes - the submitted code is wrapped in a custom `Runnable` that deals not only with `Exception` handling, but also with returning values from execution via the `Callable<T> -> Future<T>` API. If you want implementation details it's best just to look at [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java).

Comment: This is not the whole story. ThreadPoolExecutor may allow threads to die and new threads are constructed in their place. See "Keep-alive times" in the documentation for ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: @cambunctious that's around the pooling mechanic itself - which is not really related to how a `Thread` is reused.

Comment: The answer to the question "How does ThreadPoolExecutor avoid creation of new threads?" should include "it doesn't".

Comment: I am interested to know what happens with thread in pool when task sleeps for some given time. Does thread go back to pool to overtake another task and when is time to 'wake up' task, another thread from pool will take over half-done task and try to finish it, or existing thread will be just taken until task is finished. I think it's the latter, just would like someone document that part too

Comment: @ante.sabo no. Threads are fully blocking so they will not return to the pool until `run()` returns regardless of calls to sleep or blocking IO. What you talk about are, in Java terms, called Fibres and are due to be included in the JDK soon. A reactive programming library can also help here, but you need to be very careful to call it’s sleep methods (usually called something like `delay`) and not sleep itself as ... threads are fully blocking.